# How to defining class to make a way to use proper method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to change the use of method to like this. if return create connection instance. how to use that connection instance with execute method.  mysql-connector class definition in bottom.

```
const mysql = require('../libs/mysql-connector');
const client = new mysql;
const options = require('../config/database');

async index()
{
   const connection = await client.createConnection(options);

   const [rows] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM media');

   res.send(rows);
}
```

for now i use it like this.

```
await client.createConnection(options);
    
const [rows] = await client.execute('SELECT * FROM media');
    
res.send(rows);
```

libs/mysql-connector

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

class Mysql 
{
    #connection;

    async createConnection(options)
    {
        this.#connection = await mysql.createConnection(options);     
    }

    async execute(query, prepare = null)
    {
        try
        {
            const [rows, fields] = await this.#connection.execute(query, prepare);

            return [rows, fields];
        }catch(e){ console.log(e.code); }
    }
} 

module.exports = Mysql;
```

Comment: what is the point of using a wrapper which simply redirects everything to the underlying lib?

Comment: handling errors, it will overwhelming to always call handling error eachtime call query.